# extJS gridpanel loading datafrom database

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, extjs

I found this extjs script that create a empty gridpanel:

```
    var gridz = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
   // store: dstore,
        columns: [
        {id:'id', header: "Id", width: 60,  sortable: true, dataIndex: 'id'},
        {id: 'data', header: "Data", width: 200, sortable: true, dataIndex: 'data'}
        ],
        stripeRows: true,
        autoExpandColumn: 'data',
        height:350,
        width: 500,
        title:'Demo Data'
    });
```

now is question: I have table called answers, how i can put my data from database intro this grid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bit that you've commented out, 'store', is responsible for storing your data. You may wish to use a [JsonStore](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.data.JsonStore), for example, which makes a request to your server to get the answers in JSON format. You then create a column model (that's the 'columns' property in your example') for the grid that knows which fields in your store map to columns in your grid.

There are some tutorials here that it'd be worth you reading through: http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorials#Grids. They may be for older versions of ExtJS than you're using but the principle is still the same.

Comment: look, i make store, and everything works, but now i have problem, my question is relationship with table inquiries and answer on questions is relationship with inquiries, If i click on row i need to get answers on clicked question. I need sub stores? how i can do it?

Comment: It depends on how you want to display your answers, but you'll probably need a second store for your answers. Then have an event listener on the grid that listens for a click, and when the listener is fired you'll want to load your answer store, probably giving it the ID of the question as a parameter. You can then display these answers somewhere, e.g. in a second grid set up to work with your answers store.